# Collaborative editing network storage workflow

Tags: editing, software, hardware, workflow

*We got to the point where multiple editors working alone can no longer effectively tackle certain projects and move towards collaborative editing (and entire production) seems like a good idea. However, I have zero experience with something like that.*

The situation is that we have two geographically separate locations, on each of those locations there are multiple people who would need to collaborate. My idea is that we would have some sort of data server on each location, all of the media would be stored there and those two servers would sync from time to time over the internet (every night or something like that). **Is that possible?**

Another part then is the local level. I have noticed there are specialized storage solutions, usually very expensive or without publicly available price (so very very expensive I guess). **Is there some advantage to those over let's say some Synology RAID network storage connected via 10G ethernet?**

Last part of that is, should the editing itself happen on the storage, or is usual practice something like mirroring the project folder to local SSD and editing on that? I want to employ proxies (have Premiere ingest data into project folder on the server and generate proxies on ingest), but I have no idea if that will curb the data size enough to make it viable for editors to have media from the network location on the timeline. Possibly I would imagine (and that might be just my wild dream) to see mounted network drive on my PC and be able to use everything from the network storage, but being able to cache selected project folders locally on a fast SSD.

Thanks ahead for any input!

Comment: You need to be more specific. Any workflow is possible given the time and budget. Yes, different storage systems have advantages and disadvantages for different situations. I'd recommend breaking this question up into several that are much more specific with a lot more details, especially on what your budget and specific situation is.